# Where to download Sitecore PowerShell Extensions for Sitecore 9.3

Tags: powershell-extensions

I am trying to find the `Sitecore PowerShell extensions for Sitecore 9.3`. As my knowledge, Sitecore 9.3 supports SPE 6.0 but not able to find any SPE modules for Sitecore  9.3 in the marketplace (https://marketplace.sitecore.net/)

Is SPE come with Out of the box in Sitecore 9.3 or Do we need to install the SPE package?

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perform below steps to Install PSE into Sitecore:

1. Go to the Sitecore Download website from https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Accelerator/9x/Sitecore_Experience_Accelerator_930.aspx
2. Click on the highlighted link in red and Download the SPE version for SC 9.3
   [image]
3. Install the SPE module with your SC instance.

For more details about the SPE module for each SC version and How to download and install it with Sitecore. See the blog post: [PowerShell with Sitecore and Installation](https://himmatsinghdulawat.blogspot.com/2021/05/powershell-with-sitecore-and-installation.html)

Answer (score 5):

For Sitecore 9.3, you can download SPE 6.0-6.2 from the GitHub releases page https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/releases/download/6.2/Sitecore.PowerShell.Extensions-6.2.zip and install through the Installation Wizard. The SPE module installs like any other for Sitecore.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the latest releases in github instead of market place. You can take a look at the features of each release and download any version from https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/releases.

There is also a compatibility table in the sitecore powershell documentation site https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix which describes the version you need to install on your specific sitecore installation.

Answer (score 0):

You can also find the Powershell package on the download pages of SXA - e.g. for 9.3 that would be https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Accelerator/9x/Sitecore_Experience_Accelerator_930.aspx